# CRC-16-IBM implementation (JS) not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, crc, crc16

### Background

I receive a buffer of bytes that has a CRC check at the end. According to the manual, this is the CRC-16-IBM algorithm with the polynomial 0xA001 ( [reversed as seen in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) ).

### Research

To implement this I translated code from several SO questions from Java to C# into JS but nothing seems to work and I have no idea why.

### Code

Here is the implementation I am currently dealing with:

```
const crc16ibm = buffer => {

    const table = [
        0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
        0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
        0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
        0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
        0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
        0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
        0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
        0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
        0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
        0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
        0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
        0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
        0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
        0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
        0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
        0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
        0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
        0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
        0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
        0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
        0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
        0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
        0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
        0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
        0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
        0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
        0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
        0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
        0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
        0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
        0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
        0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040
    ];

    let crc = 0x0000;
    for( const byte of buffer ){
        crc = crc >>> 8 ^ table[ ( crc ^ byte ) & 0xff ];
    }

    return crc;
};

module.exports = crc16ibm;
```

Here is a test that is supposed to work:

```
const hexStr = Buffer.from( "000000000000001C0D01050000001056E924222347455420444154414F524445520D0A01", "hex");

const expectedCrc =  0x00004990;

assert( crc16ibm( hexStr ), expectedCrc ); //NOPE!
```

### What is wrong?

I have quite literally tried everything, but either the examples I am using to test my code are wrong, or I have no idea on what's going on. At this point I weight both equally.

Is the problem with the lookup table?

The manual provides a graphic with an image of a ( quite inefficient ) possible way to implement this, via repeated for loops instead of using a table:

[image]

But I would much rather use a table and find out what is actually wrong in my current algorithm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your table or code to compute the CRC described in the flow chart. There must be something wrong with your test vector.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked

```
const crc16ibm = buffer => {

    const table = [
        0x0000, 0xc0c1, 0xc181, 0x0140, 0xc301, 0x03c0, 0x0280, 0xc241,
0xc601, 0x06c0, 0x0780, 0xc741, 0x0500, 0xc5c1, 0xc481, 0x0440,
0xcc01, 0x0cc0, 0x0d80, 0xcd41, 0x0f00, 0xcfc1, 0xce81, 0x0e40,
0x0a00, 0xcac1, 0xcb81, 0x0b40, 0xc901, 0x09c0, 0x0880, 0xc841,
0xd801, 0x18c0, 0x1980, 0xd941, 0x1b00, 0xdbc1, 0xda81, 0x1a40,
0x1e00, 0xdec1, 0xdf81, 0x1f40, 0xdd01, 0x1dc0, 0x1c80, 0xdc41,
0x1400, 0xd4c1, 0xd581, 0x1540, 0xd701, 0x17c0, 0x1680, 0xd641,
0xd201, 0x12c0, 0x1380, 0xd341, 0x1100, 0xd1c1, 0xd081, 0x1040,
0xf001, 0x30c0, 0x3180, 0xf141, 0x3300, 0xf3c1, 0xf281, 0x3240,
0x3600, 0xf6c1, 0xf781, 0x3740, 0xf501, 0x35c0, 0x3480, 0xf441,
0x3c00, 0xfcc1, 0xfd81, 0x3d40, 0xff01, 0x3fc0, 0x3e80, 0xfe41,
0xfa01, 0x3ac0, 0x3b80, 0xfb41, 0x3900, 0xf9c1, 0xf881, 0x3840,
0x2800, 0xe8c1, 0xe981, 0x2940, 0xeb01, 0x2bc0, 0x2a80, 0xea41,
0xee01, 0x2ec0, 0x2f80, 0xef41, 0x2d00, 0xedc1, 0xec81, 0x2c40,
0xe401, 0x24c0, 0x2580, 0xe541, 0x2700, 0xe7c1, 0xe681, 0x2640,
0x2200, 0xe2c1, 0xe381, 0x2340, 0xe101, 0x21c0, 0x2080, 0xe041,
0xa001, 0x60c0, 0x6180, 0xa141, 0x6300, 0xa3c1, 0xa281, 0x6240,
0x6600, 0xa6c1, 0xa781, 0x6740, 0xa501, 0x65c0, 0x6480, 0xa441,
0x6c00, 0xacc1, 0xad81, 0x6d40, 0xaf01, 0x6fc0, 0x6e80, 0xae41,
0xaa01, 0x6ac0, 0x6b80, 0xab41, 0x6900, 0xa9c1, 0xa881, 0x6840,
0x7800, 0xb8c1, 0xb981, 0x7940, 0xbb01, 0x7bc0, 0x7a80, 0xba41,
0xbe01, 0x7ec0, 0x7f80, 0xbf41, 0x7d00, 0xbdc1, 0xbc81, 0x7c40,
0xb401, 0x74c0, 0x7580, 0xb541, 0x7700, 0xb7c1, 0xb681, 0x7640,
0x7200, 0xb2c1, 0xb381, 0x7340, 0xb101, 0x71c0, 0x7080, 0xb041,
0x5000, 0x90c1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53c0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
0x9601, 0x56c0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95c1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
0x9c01, 0x5cc0, 0x5d80, 0x9d41, 0x5f00, 0x9fc1, 0x9e81, 0x5e40,
0x5a00, 0x9ac1, 0x9b81, 0x5b40, 0x9901, 0x59c0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
0x8801, 0x48c0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4b00, 0x8bc1, 0x8a81, 0x4a40,
0x4e00, 0x8ec1, 0x8f81, 0x4f40, 0x8d01, 0x4dc0, 0x4c80, 0x8c41,
0x4400, 0x84c1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47c0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
0x8201, 0x42c0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81c1, 0x8081, 0x4040
    ];

    let crc = 0x0000;
    for( const byte of buffer ){
        crc = crc >>> 8 ^ table[ ( crc ^ byte ) & 0xff ];
    }

    return crc;
};

module.exports.crc16ibm = crc16ibm;
```

This is how yo can try it
/*
const crc16ibm= require("./crc16ibm").crc16ibm;     console.log((crc16ibm(Buffer.from('0C010500000007676574696E666F01','hex'))).toString(16));
*/

Comment: the result is in decimal, you must convert it to hexadecimal. parseInt(result,16)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to [improve the quality of your post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405939/250259), and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.